# What's the difference between :q and :bd command when we have many buffers?

Tags: vim

I'm a beginner in vim and I've a simple question.
What is the difference between **:q** and **:bd** command when we have many buffers ?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I tend to use `bd` more and more in many-buffer scenario to ensure the buffers I'm done with won't show up when you switch buffers with `:bn` or `:q`

Answer (score 27):

`:q` quit current window.

- only one window: quit vim.
- if you have more windows opened (splits): it closes the current window **without** deleting the buffer. You can see the buffer by `:ls`

`:bd (without argument)` delete(unload) current buffer

- only one window: delete the current buffer, but won't close the window (quit vim).
- more splits: delete the current buffer, and close the current window split.

you can test it with `:ls` to monitor the buffer changes.

Answer (score 1):

:bd (destroy empty pane)close current buffer without changes. if want you change file must save then bd

:q close file. but changes not save.

I hope it complete